# Is function overloading pointless?

Tags: c++, overloading

From what I understand function overloading just makes it more likely to have errors in a program. Why should I have a whole bunch of functions with the same name when I can just create functions with distinct names that are easier to be told apart. Can I just avoid this or is there a reason to understand this?

Comment: What would it take to convince you that function overloading doesn't "make it more likely to have errors in a program?" Because dispelling that belief is essentially step one to understanding the utility of function overloading.

Comment: Would you like a programming language that you can't reuse operator `+` for both integer addition and floating point addition? They use different machine instructions and CPU components.

Comment: What I mean by that is that if learning an aspect of programming doesn't make it easy to program or add utility there is no point imo. Why shouldn't I just create different function names? I am not complaining. I am just trying to think critically.

Comment: "Why should I have a whole bunch of functions with *similar* names" No. Function overload requires *exactly the same* name. Similar names occurs when you *don't* have function overloading.

Comment: Ugh you get my point tho instead of nickpicking my words could you answer my question? Jesus I am just trying to understand.

Comment: @TylerMos: "*What I mean by that is that if learning an aspect of programming doesn't make it easy to program or add utility there is no point imo.*" OK, sure, but what makes you think that neither of those is true of function overloading? And what does that have to do with adding errors to the program, because that seems to be a separate claim from simply not having a purpose.

Comment: The point of critical thinking is to form judgement through analysis, not forming prejudgement before acquiring relevant knowledge. And accurate and precise wording is more important whenever you claim to think critically.

Comment: Say you have a function sum. You could overload it to sum 1, 2, and 3 different numbers. Or you could just declare 3 separate functions sum1, sum2, sum3. In this example does function overloading add any utility? Or make it easier to program?

Comment: @TylerMos: And what about program errors? Where does that come into play?

Comment: The premise of this example is problematic. The function `sum` in the premise does not add any utility. The subsequent choice of whether to overload is meaningless to the discussion.

Comment: @NicolBolas After I learned function overloading my first thought was that having a whole bunch of functions with the same name would make it more likely to make a mistake. Maybe that is just my preference as a programmer.

Comment: @NickyC Can you provide an example where utility would be added by function overloading? That was my initial question. Sorry if I worded my question incorrectly I am still semi-new to programming.

Comment: @TylerMos: How would overloading make mistakes more likely? That's the problem; you have a number of very vague notions, but you're expecting other people to be very specific in their answers. We can't dispel notions if you don't really know what they are.

Comment: @NicolBolas The error would be on my part. Maybe I would incorrectly type in the number of parameters and spend 3 hours trying to figure out where I made an error.

Comment: @TylerMos I have given you an example in my very first comment. Not exactly function overloading, but they share the same idea.

Comment: @NickyC Ok thanks for the help. I think I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for function overloading is to make code more robust in maintenance. For example:

```
void f_int(int);
void f_long(long);

void g(int i) {
    f_int(i);
}
```

Now suppose that you determine that `g` should really be dealing with a `long` instead of an `int`. So you change it:

```
void g(long i) {
    f_int(i); // whoops, forgot to change this to f_long
}
```

Such a change can produce lengthy ripples, and you end up having to trace function calls throughout your source code in order to make what would be a simple change with function overloading:

```
void f(int);
void f(long);

void g(int i) {
    f(i); // calls f(int)
}

void new_g(long i) {
    f(i); // calls f(long)
}
```

This kind of thing occurs often in template programming. As an exercise, try to write this template without overloading `f`:

```
void f(int);
void f(long);

template <class T> void g(T arg) {
    f(arg);
}
```

And after doing that exercise, if you think it's not too bad, try it with half a dozen versions of `f`.

Note that "I don't need templates" is not a valid answer. <g>

Another place where overloading is critical is overloaded operators. Imagine writing this code if you couldn't overload `operator<<`:

```
int i = 3;
double d = 4.1;
long long x = 32;
my_type mt;

std::cout << i << ' ' << d << ' ' << x << ' ' << mt << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid overloading constructors since a constructor doesn't have a name. One practical example of an overloaded function is `std::to_string`. You really don't want to specify the argument type in every call, and differentiating the possibilities would be impractical in template code.